# Were the generate-* commands removed from Grails 2.3.2?

Tags: grails, command-line

When I type **generate-all**, **generate-controller** or **generate-vies**, Grails current version (2.3.2) does not recognizes them. However, these commands remains on the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.2/). Does anyone knows if these commands were removed (and the docs are not up-to-date)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `grails compile` first.

These commands are now part of the scaffolding plugin, and you might need to get grails to fetch the plugin

Comment: Be sure to add the plugin in `BuildConfig.groovy`: `compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"`

Comment: That worked! And the above entry already was in `BuildConfig.groovy`. Thanks you both!